# Trying to get text to follow the object calling it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've attached my code, tried a few different things here and there but to no avail. If someone can help out and explain why your code works that would be amazing, thank you.

I have NPCTextPerson as a component and this is the script, it shows above the object but if they move it will not update the text location.

I am looking to update the script to display the text as is, but to update and follow the object until the text disappears.

This is the "NPCTextPerson" component script attached to the game object.

```
public class NPCTextPerson : Collidable
{
    public string message;

    public float cooldown = 4.0f;
    private float lastShout;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        lastShout = -cooldown;
    }

    protected override void OnCollide(Collider2D coll)
    {
       if (Time.time - lastShout > cooldown)
       {
            lastShout = Time.time;
            GameManager.instance.ShowText(message, 25, Color.white, transform.position + new Vector3(0,0.16f,0), Vector3.zero, cooldown);
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the "Game Manager" script handling the floating text module

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(GameManager.instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(player.gameObject);
            Destroy(floatingTextManager.gameObject);
            Destroy(hud);
            Destroy(menu);
            return;
        }

        //PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();

        instance = this;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += LoadState;
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    // Resoures for the game
    public List<Sprite> playerSprites;
    public List<Sprite> weaponSprite;
    public List<int> weaponPrices;
    public List<int> xpTable;

    // References
    public Player player;
    public Weapon weapon;
    public FloatingTextManager floatingTextManager;
    public RectTransform hitpointBar;
    public Animator deathMenuAnim;
    public GameObject hud;
    public GameObject menu;

    // Logic
    public int pesos;
    public int experience;

    // Floating Text
    public void ShowText(string msg, int fontSize, Color color, Vector3 position, Vector3 motion, float duration)
    {
        floatingTextManager.Show(msg, fontSize, color, position, motion, duration);
    }
```

This is the "Floating Text" script handling all the show/update/get

```
public class FloatingTextManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject textContainer;
    public GameObject textPrefab;

    private List<FloatingText> floatingTexts = new List<FloatingText>();



    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (FloatingText txt in floatingTexts)
            txt.UpdateFloatingText();
    }

    public void Show(string msg, int fontSize, Color color, Vector3 position, Vector3 motion, float duration)
    {
        FloatingText floatingText = GetFloatingText();

        floatingText.txt.text = msg;
        floatingText.txt.fontSize = fontSize;
        floatingText.txt.color = color;
        
        floatingText.go.transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(position); // Transer world space to screen space so we can use it in the UI
        floatingText.motion = motion;
        floatingText.duration = duration;

        floatingText.Show();
    }

    private FloatingText GetFloatingText()
    {
        FloatingText txt = floatingTexts.Find(t => !t.active);

        if(txt == null)
        {
            txt = new FloatingText();
            txt.go = Instantiate(textPrefab);
            txt.go.transform.SetParent(textContainer.transform);
            txt.txt = txt.go.GetComponent<Text>();

            floatingTexts.Add(txt);
        }

        return txt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear exactly what the parameters are for your show text but you aren’t keeping a reference to it here or moving it in this code. Where are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry new to all of this, let me update my post.

Comment: What is FloatingText? Cos you haven’t shown that. This code doesn’t show the moving only adds a few more layers.  The code to move the text still isn’t there.